# Hook not working on Category page in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Я работаю над модулем для Prestashop 1.7, проблема связана с хуком.

```
 public function hookDisplayProductButtons()
    {
        $idProduct = Tools::getValue('id_product');

        if ($idProduct == 21) {
            echo("true");
        }
    }
```

На странице продукта отображается «true», если продукт с идентификатором 21 открыт. Но на странице категории он ничего не показывает.

В чем проблема?

Comment: А что выводит $idProduct ? перед тем как писать условия попробуйте посметреть какую информацию получает $idProduct.

Comment: я б сначало прописал, какие даные получает $idProduct `public function hookDisplayProductButtons()
    {
        $idProduct = Tools::getValue('id_product');
        echo($idProduct);
        if ($idProduct == 21) {
            echo("true");
        }
    }`